# Como inserir legenda em gráfico com dois eixos y no r?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Como insiro a legenda nesse gráfico, tipo a barra seria o total bruto e a linha o total liquido?

```
lines = 'Mes Acid   Obt
Jan 1450    102
Fev 1447    86
Mar 1461    87
Abr 1356    61
Mai 1398    80
Jun 1115    87
Jul 1211    82
Ago 1089    64
Set 1246    86
Out 1128    73
Nov 1204    61
Dez 1435    92'

# Importando dados
obs <-read.table(textConnection(lines),h=T) 

# Visualizando a tabela criada
head(obs)

# Niveis
levels(obs$Mes)

# Ordenando niveis
obs$Mes = factor(obs$Mes, levels=c("Jan", "Fev", "Mar", "Abr", "Mai", "Jun", 
                                   "Jul", "Ago", "Set", "Out", "Nov", "Dez"))
#Gráfico
library(ggplot2) 
ggplot(obs, aes(x = Mes)) +
   geom_bar(aes(y = Acid), fill="darkblue", stat = "identity", alpha=0.4) +
   geom_point(aes(y = Obt*14), color="#a50026", size=2, group = 1) +
   geom_line(aes(y = Obt*14), color="#a50026", size=1, group = 1) +
   scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~./14, name = "Total líquido")) +
   labs(y = "Total bruto", x = "Mês")
```

[image: figura]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Como as barras usam `fill` e as linhas/pontos usam `color`, você pode especificar escalas separadas para cada um. Coloque o nome que deseja na legenda dentro das respectivas estéticas e as cores nas opções de escala manual. Dessa maneira, as chaves da legenda corresponderão ao tipo de geometria que está usando.

```
ggplot(obs, aes(x = Mes)) +
  geom_bar(aes(y = Acid, fill="bruto"), stat = "identity", alpha=0.4) +
  geom_point(aes(y = Obt*14, color="líquido"), size=2, group = 1) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Obt*14, color="líquido"), size=1, group = 1) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~./14, name = "Total líquido")) +
  scale_fill_manual("Totais:      ", values = "darkblue") +
  scale_color_manual(NULL, values = "#a50026") +
  labs(y = "Total bruto", x = "Mês") +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(order = 1), color = guide_legend(order = 2))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4):

Acho que o código abaixo resolve o problema de maneira satisfatória, ao menos segundo os meus critérios.

```
ggplot(obs, aes(x = Mes)) +
  geom_bar(aes(y = Acid, color="Bruto"), fill="darkblue", stat = "identity", 
    alpha=0.4) +
  geom_point(aes(y = Obt*14), color="#a50026", size=2, group = 1) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Obt*14, color="Líquido") , size=1, group = 1, linetype=1) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~./14, name = "Total líquido")) +
  labs(y = "Total bruto", x = "Mês") +
  scale_color_manual(name="Totais", values=c("#9c9ec5", "#a50026"), 
    guide = guide_legend(override.aes=aes(fill=NA)))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O segredo é mapear as cores das barras e da linha dentro dos seus respectivos `aes`. Note que já chamei estas cores de *Bruto* e *Líquido*, respectivamente. Ah, e defini uma cor para o contorno da barra, pois no gráfico inicial apenas o fill estava definido (não que isto seja um problema).

A seguir, foi só criar uma `scale_color_manual`, definir o nome da legenda e os valores das cores. O problema que encontrei foi definir corretamente a cor do azul. Originalmente é um *darkblue*, mas como foi aplicado um `alpha=0.4`, a cor que percebemos é um pouco mais clara. Assim, tive que detectar exatamente qual era exatamente o tom de azul da barra com o alpha aplicado. No caso, deu #9c9ec5.

Infelizmente, não sei uma maneira de combinar *darkblue* (ou qualquer outra cor que seja) com alpha na legenda automaticamente para gerar a cor desejada.

Comment: Tá ótimo, obrigado.