# Como mudar a posição das barras/colunas e como colocar legenda

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
ggplot(data = dados, aes(x = Meses,y = T.max, width = 777600))+ 
  geom_bar(aes(y = T.max), fill="red", stat = "identity",position = "dodge" ) +  
  geom_bar(aes(y = T.med), fill="blue", stat = "identity",position = "dodge") +
  geom_bar(aes(y = T.min), fill="black", stat = "identity",position = "dodge") +
  geom_line(aes(y = P.max/4),col = "green",size = 1,group = 1) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~./0.25, name = "Precipitação (mm)")) +
  labs(y = "Temperatura", x = "Meses") +   theme_bw()+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

Estou com os seguintes problemas
-preciso colocar as barras/colunas lado a lado pois nos meus dados possuo as seguintes informações T.max,Tmed,Tmin (o comando position "dodge") não esta dando certo

- Legenda não aparece

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Mateus quanto a legenda você pode consultar no  link abaixo, pode ser útil na resposta.

[Como inserir legenda em gráfico com dois eixos y no r?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/308213/como-inserir-legenda-em-gr%C3%A1fico-com-dois-eixos-y-no-r)