# Associando gráfico de barras agrupadas com pontos ligados por linha

Tags: r, ggplot2

Boa noite

Gostaria de criar um eixo Y secundário no gráfico abaixo onde irá plotar pontos ligado por linha.

O data.frame que desejo plotar no eixo Y secundário é: `ATR = c(250,160,250,250)`

Segue abaixo os dados utilizados e um exemplo de como gostaria de elaborar o novo modelo do gráfico.

Muito obrigado.

```
TCH <- data.frame(
       Período =c("Jun", "Jul"), 
       CV6654 = c(9.38, 26.14), 
       CTC9002 = c(16.27, 47.71),
       ATR = c(250,160,250,250))

df <- gather(TCH, "Variedades", "Valor", -Período)

ggplot(df, aes(x = factor(Período, levels = c("Jun", "Jul")), y = Valor, fill = Variedades)) +

geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +

geom_label(aes(label = Valor), position = position_dodge(width = 1), show.legend = FALSE) +

scale_fill_manual(values = c("cyan2", "lightgreen")) +

labs(x = "Período", y = "", title = "TCH", subtitle = "Ganho de peso mensal") +

scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,60)) +

theme_minimal() +

theme(plot.title = element_text(vjust = 1.5, hjust = 0.5), 
    axis.title.y=element_blank(),
    axis.text.y=element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),
    axis.text.x=element_text(face = "bold"))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Ou isto? [Inserir legenda em gráfico com dois eixos y no R](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/308213/como-inserir-legenda-em-gr%c3%a1fico-com-dois-eixos-y-no-r)

Comment: O segundo exemplo ajudaria perfeitamente, porém, as barras não estão agrupadas conforme meu exemplo.